# Casting to a curiously recurring derived class

Tags: c#

I have a code base using the curiously recurring template pattern, with a base and a derived class.
In a certain method that accepts a base class parameter, I would like to check if the parameter I received is of a derived type, but I cannot cast to it.
Here's an example that illustrates the problem:

```
class Base<T> where T : Base<T> {
}

class Derived<T> : Base<T>
    where T : Derived<T> { 
}

class DerivedBanana : Derived<DerivedBanana> { 
}

class Program {

    static void DoSomething<T>(T t) where T : Base<T> {
        // CS0311: The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Derived<T>'.
        // There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'Derived<T>'.
        var d = t as Derived<T>;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        DoSomething(new DerivedBanana());
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can check in my `DoSomething` method if the `T` parameter I'm getting is actually a `Derived<T>`?

**Note**: I'm refactoring my code to avoid this situation, but I would still like to know how to do such a cast :)

**Note 2**: The suggested duplicate does not answer my question: I want to know how to *cast* to the derived type, not just check if the variable is of the derived type.

Comment: I think you just want to do `class Derived<T> : Base<Derived<T>>
{ }
` not sure if it's legal C# though.

Comment: @JHBonarius it is legal C#, but it moves the same problem to the method declaration :)

Comment: You effectively need to test `if (T is Derived<T>)`, as you're not just testing whether `t` is a `Derived<T> where T : Base<T>`, but you're testing if `t is Derived<T> where T : Derived<T>`. The test `if (T is Class)` can't be done in C# without using reflection, so I suspect you're out of luck

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Aren't you making things unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: This is a not-uncommon pattern in C# -- there's no way in `Base` to find the type of the current instance (`this.GetType()` gives you the runtime type, but there's no generic equivalent), which is needed if `Base<T>` has any factory methods / methods which accept and then return a `T` (e.g. fluent methods), so you need to hack it with the ugly `Derived : Base<Derived>`.

Comment: As I said in the note, I'm refactoring this code already. I asked about the cast out of curiosity. I think @canton7's comments are the answer here.

Comment: You need `void DoSomething<T>(T t) where T : Derived<T>` because otherwise `T` is not constrained correctly

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can check in my DoSomething method if the T parameter
> I'm getting is actually a Derived?

The `Derived<T>` class could be constrained with `Base<T>` getting a little weaker form of type safety

```
public class Base<T> where T : Base<T>
{
    public virtual Base<T> This(){
        return this as T;
    }
}

public class Derived<T> : Base<T>
    where T: Base<T>
{
    public override Derived<T> This()
    {
        return base.This() as Derived<T>;
    }
}

class DerivedBanana : Derived<DerivedBanana>
{
}

class BaseBanana : Base<BaseBanana>
{
}


class Program
{

    static void DoSomething<T>(T t) where T : Base<T>
    {
        
        T d = (T)(t.This() as Derived<T> ?? t.This() as Base<T>); 
        Console.WriteLine(d.GetType());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        DoSomething(new BaseBanana());
        DoSomething(new DerivedBanana());
    }
}
```